# Calling supabse-js createClient from GitHub workflow using Supabase CLI Action fails with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: github-actions, supabase

I have a vitest suite I'm trying to run in a GitHub workflow - the tests uses supabase-js / supabase.auth.signUp to create authenticated users. However, I keep getting ECONNREFUSED error (see below).

The workflow uses supabase/setup-cli@v1 - supabase CLI works fine.

Is the Supabase CLI action not intended to expose the web API? (If so, why not?)

```
 errno: -111,
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: 'localhost',
 port: 54321
```

Here is a minimal workflow where this happens: https://github.com/abs/sb-gh-action-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/sb_test.yaml

Comment: We would need you to share your Github Action yaml file and any relevant details regarding the issue in order to provide you the answers.

Comment: @dshukertjr here is an example: https://github.com/abs/sb-gh-action-test/actions/runs/6923111348/job/18830615036

Comment: @JohnSmith: Does this work locally for you?

Comment: @Azeem yes, it works with a locally-running Supabase service (Docker)

Comment: Right. Are these logs identical to what you see locally? I don't see docker container starting in the logs. Please verify this.

Comment: **Start db** and **Migrate db** steps succeed - they only way this can happen is if the Docker container is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this:

Replace

> supabase db start

With

> supabase start